# Angular error not showing line number in code

Tags: angular, debugging

I have an error as shown in the below picture and it is not showing any line number in my code and there is no error in terminal as well and my codebase is huge. I am getting this error in chrome console. I have tried clicking those line numbers of the bundles but i didn't understand anything there. someone please tell me how to debug these kind of errors. thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If your application running in prod mode you will see these kind of error in vendor bundle instead of actual file name. Try running application without prod in local and try to reproduce the issue then you will get to know exact file name and line number. From this error I can tell some where in your code your trying to read length property on undefined variable

Comment: check your array variables inside your app and sett all array as empty . In one array as inital u have undefined or in somewhere u assign it set undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the HTML file. from the error message, I guess angular try to read `length` property in an object variable. usually, it's happened in `ngFor`, when angular want to know the length of the Array. because you don't define the variable type (only use `any`)

to fix this, you must change the type to `Array<Object>` when declaring a variable. so when the variable is empty, the `length` will be 0

Answer (score 0):

*If you're not running in **production mode*** so this is a **compiler issue**. You may see such this behavior after employing third party logging libraries like [NGX Logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger) which can change angular default logging behavior. I don't prefer to use custom loggers and If you think like me, Sometimes it goes after :

- stopping then running build command again (e.g `ng build`)
- upgrading *nodejs* version

Unfortunately, there are few similar cases like yours unless those disturbed angular logging with additional tools like one that mentioned before. My first suggestion is Trying to log environment mode (`developement` or `production`).

Comment: i am using command `ng build --watch src`. are you saying to run app without production mode if yes what is the command ?

Comment: @Prem This is based on your configurations. There's no problem with `ng build --watch` since it's working in *developement* mode by deafult.